# Running npm application in Kubernetes

Tags: angular, npm, kubernetes

I have an angular 6 application which I run in my local as "npm start".

I would like to deploy this application in Kubernetes. I am not sure about dockerizing angular 6 based application and running in Kubernetes. Any help/pointer, please ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many great blogs on how to dockerize the angular based application. I am listing few here, you can find many more.

https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-an-angular-app/

https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/your-angular-apps-as-docker-containers-471f570a7f2

Once you're able to dockerize your application in container and successfully run it, then you can think about moving to kubernetes to orchestrate those containers.
You should start it from kubernetes official documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/)

Hope this helps.